# How do you add a timer that starts at the beginning of each level and ends when you complete the level in unreal engine 4?

Tags: unreal-4

So currently I have multiple levels in my game, and at the end of each level you automatically get teleported to the next level by a load level trigger, I am wondering how to implement a timer which starts each time a new level is loaded which the level sees and ends when the player finishes the level.

Comment: So, you mean a clock that tells you how long it took for players to finish any given level?

Comment: @liggiorgio Yes that's exactly what I mean